# mkvirtualenv cannot set directory?

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I tried to create a new virtualenv using:

```
mkvirtualenv Test_Project
```

and I got this error:

```
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR

virtualenv: error: no such option: -n
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install virtualenv and virtaulenvwrapper? via apt-get or pip?

If you did it via apt-get uninstall and use pip instead.

Comment: I used pip. This is an old VM though haven't touched it in a while could be some config is messed. Whats the best way to purge it all and start again with virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper